# Will it define a structure of structures?

Tags: c

This is the piece of code.

```
struct RTC
 {
   unsigned char seconds ;
   unsigned char minutes ;
   unsigned char hours ;
   unsigned char days ;
 } ;
 struct RTC xdata RTC_chip ;
```

Please give explanation too.

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: Multiple variables of same type should be separated by , so struct RTC xdata RTC_chip ; should be struct RTC xdata, RTC_chip ;

Comment: If that compiles, at least one of `xdata` or `RTC_chip` must be a macro that allows it to compile.  As written, `struct RTC xdata RTC_chip;` is a syntax error; you need a comma — `struct RTC xdata, RTC_chhip;` to be valid C.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement,

```
struct RTC
 {
   unsigned char seconds ;
   unsigned char minutes ;
   unsigned char hours ;
   unsigned char days ;
 } ;
```

Is a *definition* of a struct. The second statement,

```
 struct RTC xdata RTC_chip ;
```

is a *definition* of 2 variables, namely `xdata` and `RTC_chip`, of the type of the above defined struct.

Comment: if `xdata` and `RTC_chip` are variables, then there should be a comma between them.